# Android MonkeyRunner script not running on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android, eclipse, unix, monkeyrunner

I'm getting no output.

I set up monkeyrunner for Eclipse, following: http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-android-monkeyrunner-from-eclipse.html directions. I managed to get my code to 'run' cleanly within Eclipse- no errors.

From the command line I've tried both:

```
monkeyrunner [path]/MonkeyTest.py
monkeyrunner -v ALL [path]/MonkeyTest.py
```

The cursor disappears for a few seconds and then I have the prompt back and nothing happens.  'monkeyrunner' by itself produces the info + prompt:

```
Jython 2.5.0 (Release_2_5_0:6476, Jun 16 2009, 13:33:26) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_35
>>>
```

The phone I have hooked to the PC is registering because I get it's listing when I enter:

> adb devices

The only thing I can think of is that it won't execute because I'm not installing an *apk??

I'm just trying to use this to automate the setup for CTS. (i.e. turning on wi-fi, making sure all the CTS-Verifiers have authority, setting the phone not to lock, etc).  If there's a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: It looks like there are newer instructions at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/03/eclipse-working-monkeyrunner.html that might work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something to your MonkeyTest.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

print "This is MonkeyTest.py"
```

then

```
$ chmod +x MonkeyRunner.py
```

and if your monkeyrunner is in your PATH you'll be able to do

```
$ ./MonkeyTest.py
```

or

```
$ monkeyrunner MonkeyTest.py
```

or

```
$ /path/to/monkeyrunner MonkeyTest.py
```

or

```
$ /path/to/monkeyrunner /path/to/MonkeyTest/py
```

and you will be able to see the message. If you don't, something else is wrong.